# make RESTful API call ONLY by calls in java.io

Tags: java, rest

I was asked is there anyway to call RESTful API only by java.io. No java.net URL and 3rd party library. I did try to open HTTP by different reader/InputStream under java.io, it seems getting FileNotFoundExceptions, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need `java.net.Socket` to reach remote host at least. This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java documentation:

> **Package java.io**
>
> Provides for system input and output through data streams,
>   serialization and the file system.

In order to make a REST call using such such approach, you may write a REST method call into a JSON format and payload into a File then have a another application read the file that will then do the actual REST API call.

And since this is not a direct REST call, the answer to your question is that it's not possible not to use any networking module of the Java Platform to achieve what you require.

Although I wonder why you are restricted to use only `java.io` for REST API calls?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it can make RESTful call indirectly via OS command, e.g. compose curl script and use Process to execute it, it redirect output to a file and then read the output file to parse output JSON